# Картинки поверх страницы

Tags: вёрстка, позиционирование, background

Как сделать такой эффект?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поверх `background` нужно разместить 2 картинки: `ipad` и `iphone`, но я не знаю как правильно их можно позиционировать. И ещё, как можно растянуть `background` по странице?

Answer (score 1):

Для растягивание background поробуйте свойство background-size, background-attachment чтобы не скролился фон с контентом.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

ipad и iphone вставляйте вот так

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="ipad">
    <img src="" />
  </div>  
  <div class="iphone">
    <img src="" />
  </div>  
</div>
```

Через @media адаптируйте.

Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/1ro7fjfd/

Comment: Спасибо большое, но этот background - один из блоков landing page, мне не надо было ставить как задний фон.Но и на этом спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы растянуть `background`

```
body {
    background: url(....);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /*Еще есть contain и cover
    cover масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока.
    contain масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока. 
    */
}
```

А для того чтобы позицонировать разные элементы на разных слоях есть `z-index` в `css`, например:

```
#iphone {
    z-index: 2;
}

#ipad {
    z-index: 1;
}
```